# Error with Maven Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm in virtualbox and behind the organization's firewall &  proxy, I see this error, i have been trying to fix this issue since morning with no luck. Can anyone help me bypass this issue with spring boot jars.

I have the network connections set to the proxy for http and https with Native, Direct and   Manual

```
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/.../.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.2.RELEASE.pom.lastUpdated
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for demo:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.40.215] failed: Connection timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for demo:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.40.215] failed: Connection timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:422)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project demo:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/home/.../Documents/workspace-sts-3.7.2.RELEASE/SpringBoot/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for demo:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.40.215] failed: Connection timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.40.215] failed: Connection timed out
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1000)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:800)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:329)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:469)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:438)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:401)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.40.215] failed: Connection timed out
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:193)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.40.215] failed: Connection timed out
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.40.215] failed: Connection timed out
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1066)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.40.215] failed: Connection timed out
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:832)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:983)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
    ... 53 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also configure the proxy in your Maven settings.xml. Add the following snippet with the appropriate values for your environment (some of these tags might not be necessary):

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <id>myproxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
    <port>8080</port>
    <username>proxyuser</username>
    <password>somepassword</password>
    <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Documentation: http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies

Comment: This does not work for me. Any other suggestions please?